# Фильтрация массива с помощью map

Tags: javascript, функции, объекты, map

Кажется, я не до конца понимаю,как работает map. Я пытаюсь вернуть массив,который не содержит элемента с определенным id.

```js
const items = [
        { name: "Do my homework", id: 1 },
        { name: "Play with cat", id: 2 },
        { name: "Draw mother", id: 3 },
        { name: "Meet boyfriend", id: 4 }
      ];

      const onDeleted = id => {
        const notDeleted = items.map(item => {
          let result = [];
          if (item.id !== id) {
            result.push(item);
          }
          return result;
        });
        console.log(notDeleted);
      };

      onDeleted(2);
```

Comment: для этого нужен filter, а не map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для фильтрации элементов массива, есть соответствующий метод - [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const items = [
  { name: "Do my homework", id: 1 },
  { name: "Play with cat", id: 2 },
  { name: "Draw mother", id: 3 },
  { name: "Meet boyfriend", id: 4 }
];

const excludeById = id => items.filter(o => o.id !== id); 
console.log(excludeById(2));
```

В результирующий массив попадут только те элементы, для которых функция обратного вызова вернула истинное значение. Часто она содержит единственное выражение с логическим оператором - как и в нашем случае: достаточно вернуть результат неравенства (оно будет возвращать `true` если `id` не равны - а при их равенстве, результатом выражения будет `false`, и тогда элемент массива не попадет в результат).

---

А метод `map` не подходит для фильтрации по той простой причине, что предназначен он для *преобразования* элементов, и "не умеет" их пропускать... Каждое значение возвращаемое его функцией обратного вызова, в результирующем массиве займет место того элемента, для которого функция была вызвана.

Если не возвращать значение в коллбэке `map`, то элемент в результате все равно **останется** - место исходного значения элемента займет неявно возвращаемое значение `undefined`:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; 
const newArr = arr.map(v => {
  if (v % 2) return v; 
}); 
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

[map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) `создаёт новый массив с результатом вызова указанной функции для каждого элемента массива`

Тоесть достаточно просто возвращать отфильтрованные элементы в callback функции.

```js
const items = [
  { name: "Do my homework", id: 1 },
  { name: "Play with cat", id: 2 },
  { name: "Draw mother", id: 3 },
  { name: "Meet boyfriend", id: 4 }
];

const onDeleted = id => {
  const notDeleted = items.map(function(item) {
    if (item.id !== id) {
      return item;
    }
  });
  
  console.log(notDeleted);
};

onDeleted(2);
```

Comment: но ведь возвращается не отфильтрованный массив, а массив в котором какие-то элементы **заменены**